# Optimization for Storing and Retrieving Multiple Sizes of Profile Picture

Tags: sql, image, optimization

I'm creating a web application with a SQL back end for storing data. As a part of my application, user profile have profile pictures. I'll be displaying a user's profile picture throughout the application in one of two different sizes (16 x 16 and 128 x 128).

How is best for storing the picture and then retrieving a specific size of it? Should I

- Store the original picture in the database, and then resize it to the desired size when used?
- Store the picture at 128 x 128 and resize it to 16 x 16 only when I need to?
- Store the picture at both 128 x 128 and 16 x 16, and retrieve only the size needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on a product with a similar need. We keep it stored as two images in the required resolution, which correlates to the last of your possibilities. Storage is nil in our case, and there's no reason to add any overhead in retrieving images by resizing them. We process them once, when we receive them, and don't worry about it again until they change their picture. Works great.

Comment: This is what I have been leaning towards. Have you found there to be any downsides at all to this approach, or anything that one should be aware of down the road?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. It's been straight forward and working without problems.